# Angular CLI error Cannot read property 'write' of undefined

Tags: angular

When I run my project by `ng serve` 
I see this error in command prompt

```
Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at UI.write (C:\Source\Front\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\ui\index.js:56:23)
    at UI.writeLine (C:\Source\Front\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\ui\index.js:69:8)
    at Class.run (C:\Source\Front\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:237:12)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (C:\Source\Front\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Since the update Angular CLI to the last version `6.1.1`, this problem has arisen

How can I solve this problem?

Package version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.1
Node: 10.7.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.1
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.1
@schematics/angular          0.7.1
@schematics/update           0.7.1
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.7.2
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11687 This is a known and fixed issue. Until that fix goes public you can make changes from here manually. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/11690/commits

Comment: Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

related with angular-cli latest release - `6.1.0` and `6.1.1`.downgrade angular-cli to `6.0.8` and it works fine.

Comment: I'd like to use Angular CLI: 6.1.1 because of another project in my system use Angular CLI: 6.1.1

Comment: angular-cli active [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11661) for 2 days ago it will be fine in new version but now there is problem with 6.1.1

Comment: How can I install version 6.0.8 ?

Comment: ```npm uninstall -g @angular-cli``` /
```npm cache clean --force``` /
```npm install -g @angular-cli@6.0.8```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue. You still have an old `ember-cli` folder in your error logs. This folder is ***not*** part of the AngularCLI anymore. So to update your project:

First update all of the global dependencies of your system:

```
npm update -g
```

Then update your local dependencies this way:

```
rmdir /S /Q node_modules
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
ng update --all
npm install
```

It will remove your old `node_modules` folder first and then it will reinstall it properly and cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I was have the same problem and I found the solution at github issue related to the same problem

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@6.1.1
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

[Web cannot run after update angular cli to 6.1.0 #11661](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11661)