# Cannot read property 'write' of undefined - Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, node-modules

I am working on an `Angular 5` project where I'm facing issue `Cannot read property 'write' of undefined`  while trying to build and run(`ng serve`):
[image]

My `local @angular/cli version is 1.7.4` and below are the versions of `global @angular/cli, nodejs and npm`:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.1
Node: 14.17.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.17
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1402.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         14.2.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   14.2.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          14.2.1 (cli-only)
```

Below is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "Test",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.47.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.17",
    "adal-angular-ts": "^1.1.6",
    "adal-angular5": "^1.0.36",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-checklist": "^1.2.3",
    "angular-d3-charts": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-localstorage": "^1.1.5",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.6.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.3.0",
    "angular2-tinymce": "^2.1.2",
    "angular2-toaster": "^4.0.1",
    "angular4": "^1.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hellojs": "^1.16.1",
    "html2pdf": "0.0.11",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.2",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.1.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "https://github.com/Sky4CE/ng2-bootstrap-modal/tarball/v.1.0.2",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.1.7",
    "ng2cli": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-charts": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-tabs": "0.0.13",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.36",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.6.5",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "^6.1.7",
    "quill": "^1.3.5",
    "request-options": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.8.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "toggle": "^1.0.1",
    "upgrade-angular": "^0.1.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/adal": "^1.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.7",
    "@types/tinymce": "^4.5.16",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Note that a similar issue was raised earlier also [Angular CLI error Cannot read property 'write' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578019/angular-cli-error-cannot-read-property-write-of-undefined) but this fix only applies to a specific version which I unfortunately can't use.

I've tried uninstalling `@angular/cli` globally, running command `npm cache clean --force` to clean the `npm cache`(although the command showed me only a warning `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.` and no output as such) and then again installing the latest version of `@angular/cli` globally(`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`), deleting `node modules` folder and re-installing them(`npm install`)  but nothing worked.

I would highly appreciate any help whatsoever about this, thanks.

Comment: could you try `npx run start`? maybe the global cli is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is due to version differences between global and local versions of `@angular/cli` Please sync up the versions, else you can run the below command

> npx run start

above line will run only the local version of angular cli which run without any errors!