# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at new Server

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> at new Server (E:\New folder\Mohsin Projects\fishry-storefront-ppl\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:51:24)
> at Class.run (E:\New folder\Mohsin Projects\fishry-storefront-ppl\node_modules@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:235:24)
> at E:\New folder\Mohsin Projects\fishry-storefront-ppl\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

```
I am recieving this error
my node version is v14.15.1
my npm version is v6.14.8
my angular/Cli version is v1.6.7
@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.6.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter: 5.2.5
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular-devkit/architect: 0.1402.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 14.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics: 14.2.9
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.7
@schematics/angular: 14.2.9
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack-bundle-analyzer: 4.7.0
webpack-node-externals: 1.7.2
webpack: 5.75.0
```

First I was recieving this error
[Angular CLI error Cannot read property 'write' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578019/angular-cli-error-cannot-read-property-write-of-undefined)
and i used this solution to remove that error now the error description has changed
i have tried too many versions of node and @angular/cli almost every gets a brand new error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try These versions and To make your project work